# Unbiased estimator for the following survival function

Tags: survival

I have the following data, where $+$ denotes right censoring.

> $$
> 2, 6, 7^+, 8^+, 10, 11, 14^+, 16
> $$
>   I would like to find an **unbiased estimator** for $S(6)S(10)$, where $S(\cdot)$ mean survival function.

---

**My try**

KM estimate for $\hat{S}(6) = \frac{7}{8} \times \frac{6}{7} = \frac{3}{4} $, $\hat{S}(10) = \frac{7}{8} \times \frac{6}{7} \times \frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{16} $, where $\hat{S}(\cdot)$ denotes [Kaplan-Meier estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator).

But $\hat{S}(6)\hat{S}(10)$ would never work, without their independence, and I have heard that [KM estimator is biased](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72084/why-does-my-proof-for-showing-that-the-kaplan-meier-estimate-is-unbiased-not-wor), so I'm stuck at how I should proceed.

Comment: We estimate the parameters, not the statistics, such as $\hat S(6)\hat S(10).

Comment: @a_statistician, thx for the comment, edited.

Comment: What is the meaning of $S(6)S(10)$? One person survivals to 6 and 10, or two persons, one survivals to 6 another survivals to 10?

Comment: @a_statistician it's just $P(X > 6) P(X > 10)$, where $X$ is the lifetime.

Comment: For two persons, I think the estimate of $P(X_1>6)P(X_2>10) = 3/4 * 9/16$. For one person, I think it is meaningless.

Comment: @a_statistician I agree with you, but I don't know how to show $3/4∗9/16$ for $P(X_1>6)P(X_2>10)$ is unbiased.

Comment: Need two conditions: 1)KM is unbiased. 2)person 1's survival is independent from person 2's survival. 2) should be true. I do not know where you get the idea that 1) is not true.